# "Two or less/fewer"

Tags: countability

[*Couple* can mean "two (or more)''. *Pair* will almost always mean "**two (or less).**''](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/couple)

Why is *less* used here?  What's it mean?

LESS https://oed.com/oed2/00132077 , FEW https://oed.com/oed2/00084160

Answer (score -1):

No no!

"A couple of" means "a few." The "of" is very important. When Americans speak quickly, this often sounds like "A coupl'a."

"A couple" is a pair who are dating or married.

"A pair" is ALWAYS two, except in certain strange English-isms like "a pair of pants." I can't even think of another one.

Comment: A pair of scissors, a pair of eyeglasses, a pair of underwear.

Comment: _The first couple chapters of the book_ doesn't need your "A".  *Pant* is literally "pant leg " https://www.wordreference.com/definition/pant

Comment: What do you mean by **English-ism**?  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Englishism